# Можно ли автоматически прокрутить документ Word

Tags: delphi, ole

Можно ли автоматически прокрутить документ `Word` из Delphi ? Мне нужно открывать документы, прокручивать их постранично и делать скрины. т.е как программно прокрутить документ. в данный момент интересует окно Word или Notepad

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: Записываешь макрос, потом переписываешь его в делфи на вызовы методов WordApplication'а.

Comment: А нужны именно скрины? Может, проще сконвертировать документ в (к примеру) XPS-формат, или pdf? Детализируйте задачу - для чего потребовались такие, мягко говоря, нестандартные действия.

Comment: Есть папка с вложенными папками и файлами. Файлы внутри могут быть разных типов txt, jpeg, doc, xls. мне надо открывать эти файлы ли не открывая их содержимое добавлять в общий pdf. я предполагал открывать и деать скрины, но с конвертацией идея хорошая, только сейчас не могу один pdf добавить вконец другого pdf. т.е один файл я использую как приемник и в него добавляю сконвертированные файлы

Answer (score 1):

Есть парочка инструментов для автоматического захвата скроллинга: "FastStone Capture" и "SangIt" но обе платные, но лучше всего это делает FastStone Capture, т.к. позволяет сам выбрать регион для скриншота и сам "нажимает" на кнопки скроллинга (которые вы же и укажите). Мне он нравится, когда надо длинную "простыню" заскриншотить. Автоматически скролит до бесконечности...